# add facebook app settings "automatic"

Tags: facebook, settings, addition

If you look at http://iframehost.com/help/addapp and http://iframehost.com/newapp you'll see that they have a very nice way of filling in all the settings for the app. You just create the new app with a name/namespace, then copy the app id & secret key you get, fill in these at iframehost.com/newapp, and all the rest of the settings appear "automagically" in the app settings on facebook.

I understand that the app id & secret key together allows the iframehost-server to send the rest of the stuff to FB, but could anyone point me in the right direction, or even better, give me an example or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit certain properties (but not all) for your app via API – it’s all described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/